# my commands dont work in my discord server

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

im trying to make a bot for my discord server, but all my commands dont work.

im using windows and pycharm to test and use the bot. i tried many different types but nothing works. im using python 3.7

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot is active")


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
    await print("pong")
```

it doesn't crash or give an error, it just doesn't do anything in the command

Comment: Do have a `client.run("your token")` line?

Comment: yes, i even tested some message code in on_ready and that worked fine. thx for pointing out do

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = YOUR_TOKEN_GOES_HERE

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
      print("Powering up the bot")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):                    
      print("A new message!")
      await client.process_commands(message)

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
      await ctx.channel.send("Pong!")
```

Comment: Also I'm not sure, why are you using 'from discord.ext.commands import Bot'?

Comment: didn't work at all i even tried using print commands in between but still nothing.

Comment: Why are you using this >> Client = discord.Client() ??
This bit is useless here. Also if you observe, you're using smaller case client, and you're trying to do something with 'C'lient! I've edited my comment with a more elaborate snippet. Now if you're on the rewrite branch (which you haven't mentioned in your question) then it should work!

Comment: @probroj, did you get to confirm if you're on async or the rewrite branch and more importantly, did it work?